# Fluent Wait is Not working-Seleneium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This below WebElement is not present in WebPage. However I want to know about Fluent wait.
Here when webdriver trying to identify `BE_flight_flseah_btn`, its supposed to wait max 5 mins based on code,but it throws error within seconds saying no such element.

```
Wait<WebDriver> w=new FluentWait<WebDriver>(dr)
        .withTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .pollingEvery(5,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        WebElement we=w.until(new Function<WebDriver,WebElement>()
        {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver dr)
            {
                return dr.findElement(By.id("BE_flight_flseah_btn"));
            }
        });
```

why it is not waiting for 5 mins, anything wrong in this code? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have imported the correct `NoSuchElementException` class.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
```

Because if you use any ide like eclipse or Netbeans the auto import will most probably importing `import java.util.NoSuchElementException;` which is a wrong one

You are polling every 5 milliseconds and waiting for 5 minutes. So it will check 60000 times to find the element.It will affect the performance.Either increase the polling TimeUnit to Seconds or Reduce the Timeout to Seconds

**Fluent Wait:** Let’s say you have an element which sometime appears in just 1 second and some time it takes minutes to appear. In that case it is better to use fluent wait, as this will try to find element again and again until it find it or until the final timer runs out.

**Explicit Wait:** There can be instance when a particular element takes more than a minute to load. In that case you definitely not like to set a huge time to Implicit wait, as if you do this your browser will going to wait for the same time for every element.

To avoid that situation you can simply put a separate time on the required element only. By following this your browser implicit wait time would be short for every element and it would be large for specific element.

For your requirement instead of FluentWait and Wait you can use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) along with [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) though WebDriverWait is an extension of FluentWait.

You can read about the [comparison over this link](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/)

Your Condition can be handled as

```
//timeunit in seconds.
//There are two other constructors available you can see that in the links

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);

 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("BE_flight_flseah_btn")));
```

Comment: Thanks madhan.But i need to know why this is not working or anything wrong with this code?

Comment: but this script should wait for 5 mins right since the element is not present in my webpage,why it throws error within secs. @Madhan

Answer (score 0):

```
public WebElement waitForElementDisplayed(final Supplier<By> by,
                                              final int timeToWaitInSec) {
        Wait<Browser> wait = new FluentWait<>(this)
                .withTimeout(timeToWaitInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .ignoring(WebDriverException.class);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by.get()));
        WebElement foo = wait.until((Function<Browser, WebElement>) (Browser driver) -> {
            try {
                Element element = driver.findElement(by);
                if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                    return element;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        });
        return foo;
    }
```

Invoke this method - your script should be working.

Answer (score 0):

.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) - This should be imported from import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;

By default Eclipse ask to import NoSuchElementException class either from **java.util.NoSuchElementException;** or 
**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;**

If we select - java.util.NoSuchElementException; then program will not wait for maximum time as mentioned in the polling statement.

Technically, nothing is wrong with the code, it is just wrong package is imported

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.